# Unable to assign a value to a double

Tags: c++

I am working on a project. every variable used in here is stored as double.
The thing is I have a 2D velocity vector with both coordinates and I want to compute the angle between the vector and the OX axis, so I use `Theta1 = atan(v1y / v1x);`. Still, by this approach I can only get the angle from between -PI/2; PI/2, so in order to extend the range I added

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
double Theta1;
Theta1 = atan(v1y / v1x);
if (v1x < 0.0)
    if (v1y > 0.0)
        Theta1 = Theta1 + (PI/2.0);
    else
        Theta1 = Theta1 - (PI/2.0);
else;
```

When I try to use Theta1 then, it seems not to be modified by the first if operations. I mean it never adds the (+/-)PI/2.0, yet if I just try

```
cout << Theta + PI/2.0 << endl;
```

it prints Theta1 modified. What am I doing wrong? It seems like either theres some pitfall or I just don't see something simple.

Comment: You should better use `atan2`, that deals with the angle out-of-the-box.

Comment: Brought a little more information above

Comment: Could you paste the v1y and v1x you are using for test?

Comment: By the #define PI 3.14...

Comment: What's the value of `v1x`?

Comment: The coords are actually generated by the other part of my program. I can bring some examples:
v1 = -59x-51
Theta1 = -49.1596;
v2 == 0
v1 = -140x127
Theta1 = 47.7875;

Comment: How do you determine that it never adds (or seems to add) the `±PI/2`? By the way, you should add/subtract `PI`, not `PI/2`.

Comment: I determine this by using

`cout << Theta1;`

after modifying. Then I try

`cout << Theta1 + PI/2.0; `

and this seems to work

Comment: @patryk Print it out before and after modifying. I suspect when `v1x` is negative, you will see that the value changed, it is just not the correct value you expected.

Comment: You're going to have some trouble when v1x == 0. I second the suggestion to use `atan2` instead of `atan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The period of the tangent is `π`, so your adjustment is not correct, it should be `±π`. As is, when both coordinates are negative, the quotient, and the result of `atan` will be positive, a value between `0` and `π/2`. Then you subtract `π/2` and get a negative value between `-π/2` and `0`, but you should get one between `-π` and `-π/2` geometrically.

Also, you should use `atan2`, which gives you the correct angle without adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

If `v1x` is greater than or equal to zero, `Theta` will not be modified because it then enters the `else` clause of the outer `if` statement, which contains no code.

If `v1x` *is* negative then, short of a compiler bug, `Theta` *will* change. I would suggest placing:

```
std::cout << Theta1 << '\n';
```

immediately before and after the `if` statement for verification.

Comment: When `v1x` that is horizontal coordinate of the vector is greater than 0, then there is no need of adding what I want to add.

Comment: @patryk, you miss my point. You stated the value is not changing.  I gave a plausible reason why, based on the info given (which didn't include the `v1x` value). What _is_ the value of `v1x` when this code runs? If it's non-negative, this answer explains why.

Comment: When v1x is greater than 0, then I don't need theta to change because atan returns a proper value. Yet if x coord is negative, then basing on y I want to determine if theta is between `+pi/2` and `+pi` or `-pi` and `-pi/2`. This is a set of data that should make theta be around 135 deg
`v1 = -99x94
Theta1 = 46.484`

Comment: @patryk, let me re-ask: _what is the value of v1x when your test indicates theta isn't changing?_ That is VITAL information. `-99x94` as the "value" for v1 makes no sense in the context of v1x.

Comment: Okay, I found my mistake. Needed to read your replies a couple of times before getting the point. Thank you very much

Comment: Right, that might be confusing. That meant `v1x` was -99 and `v1y` 94.